# How to use Jackson TypeReference for generic class

Tags: java, angularjs, generics, jackson

I'm new here and know that the problem below has probably been discussed many time but I can't find a clear solution to my problem...

So, I work on an application made of two parts :
- a front-end in AngularJS
- a back-end in Spring MVC
Both part exchange in JSON format with Jackson.
Which associate the JSON  to View Object (VO)

So I have the Javascript function below on FrontEnd :

```js
    /**
    * Reference save.
    * @param reference The reference to save
    * @param type Type of reference
    */
    save: function(reference,type) {
     return $http.post('myApplication/reference/save/'+ type, reference);
    }
```

Sending data to the Java function below :

```
         **
     * Reference Controller.
     * @param <VO> Reference
     * @param <E> Entity
     */
    @RequestMapping("/reference/")
    @Controller
    public class ReferenceController<VO extends AbstractReferenceEntityVO, E extends AbstractReferenceEntity> {

    /** Reference management service. */
    @Autowired
    private ReferenceService<VO, E> referenceService;

    /**
     * Reference save method.
     * @param referenceVO View Object of the reference to save
     * @param type Reference type
     * @return VO
     */
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save/{type}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public VO save(@Validated @RequestBody final VO referenceVO,
            @PathVariable final String type)
    {
        return this.referenceService.save(type, referenceVO);

    }
}
```

This JAVA Class is a generic one because this controller can receive/send 2 kind of ReferenceVO (VO1 & VO2) both Inheriting from an Abstract Class (AbstractReferenceEntityVO).

Today I have the jackson issues below when trying to call this save function :

```
    *Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of myApplication.AbstractReferenceEntityVO, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
     at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1a956b3d; line: 1, column: 1]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:889)
        at 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2798)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:205)
    ... 88 more*
```

After researches I found I have to use jackson "TypeReference" to manage the Generic class. So I guess I have to specify to Jackson which inherited VO it have to use for mapping so I need to do first a condition on the "type" of my reference to associate with the right VO...

This is my ObjectMapper & XML configuration :

```html
 <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="applicationConversionService">
    <mvc:message-converters>
   <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
     <property name="objectMapper">
     <bean class="myApplication.CustomObjectMapper" />
    </property>
   </bean>
  </mvc:message-converters>
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

```
/**
 * Mapper JSON objets.
 */
public class CustomObjectMapper
    extends ObjectMapper
{
    /** Id. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6488036405547458525L;

    /** Constructor. */
    public PlageObjectMapper()
    {
        super();
        this.registerModule(new JodaModule());
        this.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        this.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

        TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<AbstractReferenceEntityVO>() { 
            // if(type== "TYPE_1") {
            //    TODO
            // } else {
            //    TODO
            // }
        };
    }
}
```

Does someone already have to do something similar ? Or how to use the TypeReference in my case ? To be honnest I'm a bit lost of what to do !

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass a type identifier as a field in your json. Annotate your base class with `@JsonTypeInfo` to specify the name of the field and the identifier to use. By default the field name is `@class` if you're using the class name as an identifier.

See the wiki page on [polymorphic deserialisation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for details.

Example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Scratch {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerException, SAXException {
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"@class\": \"Scratch$B\", \"payload\": \"hello, world.\"}", A.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"@class\": \"Scratch$C\", \"payload\": \"hello again.\", \"extra\": 1}", A.class));
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
    abstract public static class A {
        abstract public String getPayload();

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            try {
                return "I'm a " + getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        private String payload;

        @Override
        public String getPayload() {
            return payload;
        }

        public void setPayload(String payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }
    }

    public static class C extends B {
        private int extra;

        public int getExtra() {
            return extra;
        }

        public void setExtra(int extra) {
            this.extra = extra;
        }
    }
}
```